# Table with footnote

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx, ctable

I have a table and some of the number inside has some symbol like * and ** 
which should be explianed as footer ( at the end of the table not the page) I dont know how to do that and I dont want to change my code 
my code looks like this

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption  {\bf Performance at First Doubles Matches}  % title name of the table
    \centering  % centering table
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c }  % creating 4 columns
        \hline
        % here is the info 
        \hline
        % I need the foot note here ( I dont know if it is called fotenote or not ??) but I need the related info at the end of the table 
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:PPer}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like in this question: [How to align p-values description in the notes of a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48717/how-to-align-p-values-description-in-the-notes-of-a-table)

Answer (score 15):

*Without changing the code:*
Add an extra row at the bottom, merge the cells with `\multicolumns` and put the footnote manually there, i.e. format it with superscript and footnote text. A MWE (*NB! Ugly spacing*):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lccc}  % creating 4 columns

\hline \\
test & test & test & test\textsuperscript{*} \\ % here is the info 
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textsuperscript{*}\footnotesize{The footnote}}

\end{tabular}

\caption{\textbf{Performance at First Doubles Matches}}  % title name of the table
\label{tab:PPer}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**NB!!:** Please, use the package [booktabs](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to get nicer spacing and lines.

[image: Compiled MWE]

A prettified MWE_

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]

\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}  % creating 4 columns

\toprule
\textbf{H1} &\textbf{H2} & \textbf{H3} & \textbf{H4} \\ \midrule
testtest & test & testtest & testtesttesttest\textsuperscript{*} \\ % here is the info 
testtest & test & testtest & testtesttesttest\textsuperscript{**} \\
testtest & test & testtest\textsuperscript{***} & testtesttesttest \\\midrule 
testtest & test & testtest & testtesttesttest\\
testtest & test & testtest & testtesttesttest\\    \midrule[.5pt]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textsuperscript{*}\footnotesize{The first footnote}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textsuperscript{**}\footnotesize{The second footnote}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textsuperscript{**}\footnotesize{The third footnote}}

\end{tabular}

\caption{\textbf{Performance at First Doubles Matches}}  % title name of the table
\label{tab:PPer}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Changing the code*
Use the package [`threeparttable`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable), or use the package [`longtable`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/longtable), which support footnotes and can be used even if the table does not span pages. You have to change you code, though.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example using [threeparttable](http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.pdf) :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Data from the experiment}
    \label{tab:data}
    \begin{tabular}{c D{.}{.}{2.3} D{-}{{}-{}}{2.2} D{-}{\text{--}}{1.2} }
      \toprule
      Test & \mc{Number} & \mc{Difference} & \mc{Interval}\\
      \midrule
      t&12.3    & \beta_3-\beta_2  & 2-6   \\
      e&4.567 & \beta_4-\beta_3  & 7-8\tnote{\textdagger}  \\
      \addlinespace
      s&8.90   & \beta_5-\beta_4  & 9-17 \\
      \midrule
      t&10.11 & \beta_6-\beta_5  & 1-17 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[\textdagger] and all other cyclic permutations
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
%\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: my threeparttable]

I made this example as an reminder for myself, and it demonstrates more than you need(nice spacing, aligning on symbols, ...), but it should be easy to see what is relevant for you.

Comment: Hi, why you can type `\beta` without left and right `$`? Could you explain why? I do not understand `D{-}{{}-{}}{2.2}`. Thanks!

Comment: @Eden Harder: It is the dcolumn package by David Carlisle. It is all explained on the first page of the manual: http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/dcolumn.pdf

Comment: Thanks! The document explains that "It should be noted that dcolumn always uses math mode for the digits as well as the separator."

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the ctable package. If you make a complete example containing those *'s (I don't see any here) we can try to adapt it. You'll get something like:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctable,geometry}
\begin{document}
\ctable[
      caption = {\bf Performance at First Doubles Matches},
        label = tab:PPer,
          pos = h
    ]{l c c c}{
      \tnote[*]{my first footnote}
      \tnote[**]{my second footnote}
    }{\FL
      123\tmark[*] & 345 &456&567\NN
      123  & 345 &456&567\tmark[**]\LL
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need different marks to the usual counters, a simple method is include the table in a minipage. By default the marks will be  a,b,c ... instead of 1,2,3... but the example show how to change to another counters, including the  numeric counter of the normal text (probably useless, I know ...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Text before a table\footnote{A normal foot page note} \par

\bigskip


\begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth}%
\renewcommand\footnoterule{ \kern -1ex}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
aaa\footnote{First normal (alphabetic) foot table} & aaa  & aaa\\
aaa & aaa & aaa\footnote{Another table note}\\
aaa & \footnote{One more}aaa & aaa\\
aaa\footnote{Last footnote} & aaa & aaa\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}\\% 
\end{minipage}


\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth}%
\renewcommand\footnoterule{ \kern -1ex}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
aaa\footnote{First customized (fnsymbol) foot table} & aaa  & aaa\\
aaa & aaa & aaa\footnote{Another table note}\\
aaa & \footnote{One more}aaa & aaa\\
aaa\footnote{Last footnote} & aaa & aaa\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}\\% 
\end{minipage}


\bigskip


\begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth}%
\renewcommand\footnoterule{ \kern -1ex}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\Roman{mpfootnote}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
aaa\footnote{First  customized (Roman)  foot table. Try also roman y Alph styles} & aaa  & aaa\\
aaa & aaa & aaa\footnote{Another table note}\\
aaa & \footnote{One more}aaa & aaa\\
aaa\footnote{Last footnote} & aaa & aaa\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}\\% 
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth}%
\renewcommand\footnoterule{ \kern -1ex}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
aaa\footnote{Independentlly numbered foot notes. } & aaa  & aaa\\
aaa & aaa & aaa\footnote{Another table note}\\
aaa & \footnote{One more}aaa & aaa\\
aaa\footnote{Last footnote} & aaa & aaa\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}\\% 
\end{minipage}

\bigskip



\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth}%
\renewcommand\footnoterule{ \kern -1ex}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
aaa & aaa {\scriptsize\footnotemark} & aaa\\
aaa & aaa & aaa \\
aaa & aaa & aaa{\scriptsize\footnotemark}\\
aaa & aaa & aaa\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}\\% 
\scriptsize\footnotemark[2]{Foot note numbered as normal page notes} \\
\hspace{2em}\scriptsize\footnotemark[3]{Another note}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

Text after a  table\footnote{Another page note}


\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]