# footnote won't show up in my document

Tags: header-footer, footnotes

I'm trying to add a footnote using `\footnote{foobar}`. But it won't show up
in the footer of the document. I believe this is due to the fact that I manually
changed the sizes of the layout of the document. Can anyone suggest a fix without changing the geometry of the layout. Here is the preamble to my `.tex` code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}

%the following code I think messes with footer width/height of the document.
\textheight=8.5in \textwidth=6.5in
\topmargin=-1in \oddsidemargin=0in

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c }
\toprule
Course No. & Course title & Credits & Grade & Institution \\
\midrule
Math 644    & Real Variables & 5    & A & LLM \footnote{foobar} \\
Math 456    & Algebra I                 & 3 & A & LLM \\
\midrule
        & Total Transfer Credits     &\fbox{18} &   &   \\
\bottomrule


\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: There must be something else, because with the code you've provided I'm able to display footnotes.

Comment: Don't you think that the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is more suited to adjust page size? Anyway, that is not the issue here. I do not see any problem with footnote for the preamble you provided. Please make the file as minimal as possible. Then keep commenting out one package or command at a time. Perhaps you will find the offending one by the process of elimination.

Comment: Ok I just realized that. But I am trying to add a footnote inside a tabular environment and the footnote does not show up in that case. I will edit my code to reflect this.

Comment: If that is the case, please take a look at this, [Footnotes for tables in LaTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888817/footnotes-for-tables-in-latex)

Comment: Take a look at the `threeparttable` package and environment.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68760/11604