# Footnotes on tabularx when two tables are in the same environment, via subfloat

Tags: footnotes, subfloats, tabularx

I currently have two tables made with the `tabularx` package, side by side. I put them side by side using the `subfloat` command of the `subfig` package (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side)), that allows me to write a title (and to reference) each table separately as 1.1a and 1.1b.

My problem is the following: in these tables there are some values that have to share a common footnote. When I try to use the `\footnote{text}` command the number of the footnote appears, but the text does not.

How can I solve this? If possible, I would like the text to appear at the bottom of the **table**, but it's not so terrible if it appears at the bottom of the page.

Thank you very much in advance. I add a MWE, in which the numbers with asterisk should have the footnote I mentioned.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Title of the two-table-environment.}
    \label{table:environment}
    \subfloat[Title of the first table]{
    \label{table:first_table}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{lc*{2}{Y}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{Text too long spanning two columns yay!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
        Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
        Context 1   & $100*$    & $0.5336$\\
        Context 2   & $100$     & $0.2109$\\
        Context 3   & $100*$    & $0.3897$\\
        Context 4   & $100*$    & $-0.1376$\\
        Context 5   & $100*$    & $-0.7640$\\
        Context 6   & $100$     & $-0.0792$\\
        Context 7   & $100*$    & $-11.4119$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    }
    \subfloat[Title of the second table]{
    \label{table:second_table}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{lc*{2}{Y}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{Text too long spanning two columns hooray!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
        Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
        Context 1   & $40.7359$ & $53.7044$\\
        Context 2   & --        & -- \\
        Context 3   & $46.6164$ & $16.2185$\\
        Context 4   & --        & -- \\
        Context 5   & $28.4038$ & $70.5398$\\
        Context 6   & $57.4703$ & $59.2224$\\
        Context 7   & --        & -- \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat a little and put your footnotes in a row below your table.  Since you're using `tabularx`, you can do it with `\multicolumn`.  I tend to put this kind of footnotes in an inline enumeration separated by `\quad`.  With a `\label` attached to your items, you can `\ref` them back.

Also note that you have a series of unwanted spaces in your code which you have to hide with `%` at the end of lines.  Also, you define 4 columns `lc*{2}{Y}` where you only use 3. Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Title of the two-table-environment.}
  \label{table:environment}
  \subfloat[Title of the first table]{%
    \label{table:first_table}%
    \begin{tabularx}{0.49\textwidth}{@{}l*{2}{Y}@{}}
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{%
        Text too long spanning two columns yay!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
      Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
      Context 1   & $100\ref{tab:fn1}$    & $0.5336$\\
      Context 2   & $100$     & $0.2109$\\
      Context 3   & $100\ref{tab:fn2}$    & $0.3897$\\
      Context 4   & $100\ref{tab:fn1}$    & $-0.1376$\\
      Context 5   & $100\ref{tab:fn2}$    & $-0.7640$\\
      Context 6   & $100$     & $-0.0792$\\
      Context 7   & $100\ref{tab:fn1}$    & $-11.4119$\\
      \bottomrule
      \noalign{\vspace{3pt}}
      \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{0.49\textwidth}@{}}{%
        \raggedright\footnotesize
        \begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\quad,ref=\textsuperscript{\arabic*}]
        \item My footnote\label{tab:fn1}
        \item My other referenced footnote which is also longer\label{tab:fn2}
        \end{enumerate*}}
    \end{tabularx}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Title of the second table]{%
    \label{table:second_table}%
    \begin{tabularx}{0.49\textwidth}{@{}l*{2}{Y}@{}}
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{%
        Text too long spanning two columns hooray!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
      Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
      Context 1   & $40.7359$ & $53.7044$\\
      Context 2   & --        & -- \\
      Context 3   & $46.6164$ & $16.2185$\\
      Context 4   & --        & -- \\
      Context 5   & $28.4038$ & $70.5398$\\
      Context 6   & $57.4703$ & $59.2224$\\
      Context 7   & --        & -- \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  }%
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Title of the two-table-environment with spurious spaces}
    \label{table:environment}
    \subfloat[Title of the first table]{
    \label{table:first_table}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{lc*{2}{Y}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{Text too long spanning two columns yay!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
        Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
        Context 1   & $100*$    & $0.5336$\\
        Context 2   & $100$     & $0.2109$\\
        Context 3   & $100*$    & $0.3897$\\
        Context 4   & $100*$    & $-0.1376$\\
        Context 5   & $100*$    & $-0.7640$\\
        Context 6   & $100$     & $-0.0792$\\
        Context 7   & $100*$    & $-11.4119$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    }
    \subfloat[Title of the second table]{
    \label{table:second_table}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{lc*{2}{Y}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{Text too long spanning two columns hooray!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
        Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
        Context 1   & $40.7359$ & $53.7044$\\
        Context 2   & --        & -- \\
        Context 3   & $46.6164$ & $16.2185$\\
        Context 4   & --        & -- \\
        Context 5   & $28.4038$ & $70.5398$\\
        Context 6   & $57.4703$ & $59.2224$\\
        Context 7   & --        & -- \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This is the same solution I suggest in my answer.

Comment: @Sveinung - But I provided code `;-)` In this case you should vote to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the code! Now I have another doubt: you said that I have a series of unwanted spaces in the code, and that can be hidden with `%` at the end of lines. How can I know, in a general table, where those spaces are located? I've just applied the `%` in just one table, compiled, and I can't see a difference.

Edit: I zoomed and now I can see the spaces, nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use manual footnote, i.e. add an additional row to the first table, and put the footnote text there inside a `\multicolumn` command spanning the correct number of columns. The footnote mark can be put in a `\textsuperscript`- command at the correct places in the two tables.

Have look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68618/9632) for further description and code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `tabular` inside a `minipage` (inside the `\subfloat`, if not instead of).  Note that footnotes behave entirely differently inside minipages.  Also note that `minipage` changes `\textwidth`.

I added command \repeatfootnote in case you wanted the same footnote on all of them (which seemed likely from context).  `\footnotemark` does **not** match `\footnote` inside a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\repeatfootnote}[1][\empty]% #1 = \thempfn for this mark (optonal)
 {\ifx\empty#1\relax \@makefnmark
  \else\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\itshape #1}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Title of the two-table-environment.}
    \label{table:environment}
    \subfloat[Title of the first table]{%
    \label{table:first_table}
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lc*{2}{Y}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{Text too long spanning two columns yay!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
        Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
        Context 1   & $100\footnote{test}$    & $0.5336$\\
        Context 2   & $100$     & $0.2109$\\
        Context 3   & $100\footnote{another}$    & $0.3897$\\
        Context 4   & $100\repeatfootnote$    & $-0.1376$\\
        Context 5   & $100\repeatfootnote[a]$    & $-0.7640$\\
        Context 6   & $100$     & $-0.0792$\\
        Context 7   & $100\repeatfootnote[b]$    & $-11.4119$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    \end{minipage}%
    }\hfill
    \subfloat[Title of the second table]{%
    \label{table:second_table}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.49\textwidth}{lc*{2}{Y}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{>{\setlength\hsize{2\hsize}}Y}{Text too long spanning two columns hooray!}\\ \cmidrule(l){2-3}
        Column 1    & Metric 1  & Metric 2 \\ \midrule
        Context 1   & $40.7359$ & $53.7044$\\
        Context 2   & --        & -- \\
        Context 3   & $46.6164$ & $16.2185$\\
        Context 4   & --        & -- \\
        Context 5   & $28.4038$ & $70.5398$\\
        Context 6   & $57.4703$ & $59.2224$\\
        Context 7   & --        & -- \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```